# Mostrar un archivo desde una base de datos SQL Server en PHP

Tags: php, sql

Que tal.

Estoy trabajando con php y SQL Server. Estoy intentando extraer los archivos guardados en un campo tipo **image** (es el pdf de una factura). El campo contiene un valor como el siguiente:

`0x255044462D312E37200A25E2E3CFD3200A312030206F626A200A3C3C200A2F54797065202F436174616C6F67200A2F5061676573203220302052200A2F506167654D6F6465202F5573654E6F6E65200A2F566965776572507265666572656E636573203C3C200A2F46697457696E646F772074727565200A2F506167654C61796F7574202F53696E67...`

Quiere poder convertir ese valor en un archivo `PDF` mediante `PHP`.

Agradezco la ayuda.

Comment: Ya intente anteriormente el método que mencionas. Pero al momento de abrir el pdf que se genera obtengo el error: "Se ha producido un error al cargar el documento PDF.". Entonces pensé que estaba generandolo de forma erronea o la codificación tendría que pasarla antes por otra función

Comment: Julian Cabanillas, encontraste solucion al problema, tengo el mismo problema y no he encontrado solucion.

Answer (score 0):

Es un tipo blob, por lo que cambiando el header te valdra.

```
$gotten = @mysql_query("select * from pdf order by pid desc limit 1");
$row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($gotten);
$bytes = $row[data];
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="thing.pdf"');
print $bytes;
```

Comment: Ya intente anteriormente el método que mencionas. Pero al momento de abrir el pdf que se genera obtengo el error: "Se ha producido un error al cargar el documento PDF.". Entonces pensé que estaba generandolo de forma erronea o la codificación tendría que pasarla antes por otra función